# how to upload image to different column php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

here am trying to insert images image 1, and image 2 but only add one 
    image will be added second not be add in database please guide me

```
function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
{
    if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
    switch($imagetype)
    {
    case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
    case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
    case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
    case 'image/png': return '.png';
    default: return false;
    }
}
$_FILES["image"]["name"]; 
$file_name=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
$temp_name=$_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$imgtype=$_FILES["image"]["type"];
$ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
$imagename=date("d-m-Y").'-'.time().$ext;
$target_path = "../images/".$imagename;

if($file_name){

    move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path);   
}
$query="INSERT INTO `student`(`image1`,`image2`,VALUES ('$image1','$image2'");
```

Comment: Where are `$image1` and `$image2` assigned? Seems like you try to save the path to the database, not the whole image

Comment: i am confused, i want to save two images in two column i have no code.. can you give code...

Comment: Where are the two images comingfrom? Are there two image inputs in the form?

Comment: yes.can you give me code how to save image

Answer (score 0):

I assume your form has two inputs, something like:

```
<input type="image" name="image1">
<input type="image" name="image2">
```

You can write a function that saves an image from a given parameter name, and returns the filename.

```
function save_image($param) {
    $file_name=$_FILES[$param]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES[$param]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES[$param]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y").'-'.time().$ext;
    $target_path = "../images/".$imagename;

    if($file_name){
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path);   
    }
    return $target_path;
}
```

Then you can process each input:

```
$image1 = save_image("image1");
$image2 = save_image("image2");
$query="INSERT INTO `student`(`image1`,`image2`) VALUES ('$image1','$image2'");
```

Comment: nothing happen..image path will blank  INSERT INTO `student`(`image1`, `image2`) VALUES ('',''')

Comment: Do you have two inputs `<input name="image1" type="image">` and `<input name="image2" type="image">`? That's what I assumed.

Comment: Have you checked `var_dump($_FILES)` to see if it contains what you expect?